# Pandas: reading csv and pivoting data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to create a pandas Data Frame from a file which is in a format similar to that of comma separated value, but without a row for headers. On each row the file contains a user ID, a movie ID, and a Rating that the corresponding user gave the corresponding movie. I'd like to turn it into a data frame with movie ID for the y axis, user ID for the x axis, and the rating as the value in each "cell". How can i do this? So far everything i have seen only allows me to set the y axis, and not the x axis when directly reading from comma separated value to data frame.

data format:(time is the last one, I can leave it out as the intention is to compute similarity in ratings between users

```
1   1   5   874965758  
1   2   3   876893171  
1   3   4   878542960  
1   4   3   876893119  
1   5   3   889751712  
1   7   4   875071561  
1   8   1   875072484  
1   9   5   878543541  
1   11  2   875072262  
1   13  5   875071805
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way via [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""1   1   5   874965758  
1   2   3   876893171  
1   3   4   878542960  
1   4   3   876893119  
1   5   3   889751712  
1   7   4   875071561  
2   2   1   875072484  
2   3   5   878543541  
2   4  2   875072262  
2   5  5   875071805  """)

# read csv file, replace mystr with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, delim_whitespace=True, header=None,
                 usecols=[0, 1, 2], names=['user', 'movie', 'rating'])

# restructure dataframe via pivot_table
res = df.pivot_table(index='movie', columns='user', values='rating',
                     fill_value=0, aggfunc=np.mean)

print(res)

# user   1  2
# movie      
# 1      5  0
# 2      3  1
# 3      4  5
# 4      3  2
# 5      3  5
# 7      4  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a multi-level index (with [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) or during read_csv) and then [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) it.

```
df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv') # Assumes there are column headers.
df.set_index(keys=['movieID','userID']).unstack()
```

[The resulting dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meiIF.jpg)